# PHP urlencode a URL post field

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl to call an API POST and pass 15 post fields, one being an actual wbsite URL. For example

https://www.test.com?URL=https://www.myurl.com;&Name=John

Using urlencode converts the characters in the URL post field and the API receiving the POST call does not recognize it as an actual URL. Is there any way to keep the URL string as is when positing?

Comment: No, there is no way to send your URL as is, you should decode it on your backend

Comment: The `;` looks like a mistake, perhaps?

Comment: Are you using the curl functions within PHP? Could you show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `GET` query arguments, you need to urlencode the value, then decode it on the backend:

```
https://www.test.com?URL=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com
```

And then:

```
urldecode($_GET['url'])
```

For `POST`, the same is true for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but doesn't matter for `application/json`.

> Also, just a heads up, you have an extra `;` in your URL, which would make it invalid if you included it.

**Edit:**

I will additionally add, that in general, it's good practice to *always* urldecode values received from query arugments/form data. The general thought here being that, while you may not *want* urlencoded data, that's the way the web is *built* - You should build your code in a way that it's up to the client. This is considered an important step in data sanitation, and should always happen before validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use php builtin method to decode the url encoded data.

```
$actualUrl = urldecode ($_GET ['url']);
```